# How do you add custom fonts in TCPDF?

Tags: php, fonts, tcpdf

I would like to add a custom font to a pdf I'm generating using TCPDF.  I might be missing something but [the docs](http://www.tcpdf.org/fonts.php) seem to be out dated.  They are referencing the `addTTFfont()` function but I think it's been deprecated and no longer exists in the latest version of TCPDF.

I read that I need to convert the ttf file and put it in the fonts folder so I ran:

```
php/tcpdf/tools/tcpdf_addfont.php -i php/font/rumpelstiltskin-webfont.ttf
```

and it generated these files which are now in the fonts folder:

```
rumpelstiltskinwebfont.ctg.z
rumpelstiltskinwebfont.z
rumpelstiltskinwebfont.php
```

Then I tried to add the font:

```
$pdf->addFont('rumpelstiltskin');
$pdf->SetFont('rumpelstiltskin', '', 14, '', false);
```

but I'm getting an error:

```
TCPDF ERROR: Could not include font definition file: rumpelstiltskin
```

Comment: maybe you have to give the addFont function the full path to the files. Looks like it's not finding the file.

Comment: @Loopo It wasn't the full path that it needed but you were close.  I was using the font's name and it wanted the file name.  Thanks for the comment, it helped me figure it out.

Comment: I think you could go by this way:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263588/how-to-implement-custom-fonts-in-tcpdf

Comment: getting error `Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.` when I visited your suggested link https://tcpdf.org/fonts/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I figured out my issue, I was almost there.

Here is a step by step:

First convert your font using the `tcpdf_addfont.php` tool font in the TCPDF `tools` folder by command line:

```
php php/tcpdf/tools/tcpdf_addfont.php -i php/font/rumpelstiltskin-webfont.ttf
```

This will generate the required files and put them in the TCPDF `fonts` folder.  Check the fonts folder and copy the name of the font, in my case it was `rumpelstiltskinwebfont`.

In your code set the font using the font file's name and write a line of text:

```
$pdf->SetFont('rumpelstiltskinwebfont', '', 14, '', false);
$pdf->Write(0, 'Fill text', '', 0, '', true, 0, false, false, 0);
```

That's it.  Hope this helps someone.  :)

Comment: This solution worked, but I had to modify the command line piece a little.

I copied the Arial font file from the windows fonts directory to the fonts directory within TCPDF.

Once I was in the TCPDF folder on the command line I ran:

php tools/tcpdf_addfont.php -i fonts/arial.ttf

Comment: `php D:\aplicationname\vendor\tecnickcom\tcpdf\tools\tcpdf_addfont.php -i garamondregular.ttf` converted font from ttf file to 3 files `garamond.ctg.z`, `garamond.php` and `garamond.z` at `D:\aplicationname\vendor\tecnickcom\tcpdf\fonts` path. Include this font in pdf code `$pdf->SetFont('rumpelstiltskinwebfont', '', 14);` It worked like charm. Happy to help you :)

Answer (score 7):

Got this answer in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263588/how-to-implement-custom-fonts-in-tcpdf) and resolved for me. You just need to use the first parameter, the path of the font file. Worked with TTF and OTF fonts.

It generates a name string to use with `$pdf->SetFont($fontname, '', $font_size);`

Hope it helps.

---

The latest TCPDF version automatically convert fonts into TCPDF format using the `addTTFfont()` method. For example:

```
// convert TTF font to TCPDF format and store it on the fonts folder
$fontname = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont('/path-to-font/FreeSerifItalic.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 96);

// use the font
$pdf->SetFont($fontname, '', 14, '', false);
```

For further information and examples, please check the [TCPDF Fonts documentation page](https://tcpdf.org/docs/fonts/).

NOTE: Once the font has been converted, TCPDF no longer requires the TTF file or the above call to `addTTFfont()`!

Comment: getting error `Oops! That page can't be found.`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert ttf fonts with http://fonts.palettize.me and then put uncompressed result in fonts folder into tcpdf class. Then you can add it with $pdf->SetFont('rumpelstiltskinwebfont', '', 14); using the name of the file

Answer (score 0):

Since TCPDF (version 6.2.6) you can use `TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont` directly instead of `AddFont`.

TCPDF makes three files out of the ttf and puts them into the directory "font" of TCPDF. Once these have been created, they can be used for all future PDFs.

**Example:**
First (for simplicity) I created a folder in the font folder of TCPDF with the name of the new font, in my example *"arialuni"* and copied my *ttf* of this font into it.

If I want to create my font files in a single separate file that does not use Composer autoload, I have to include TCPDF once and also specify the correct path to my ttf.

```
require_once('vendor/tecnickcom/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$fontname = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont('vendor/tecnickcom/tcpdf/fonts/arialuni/arialuni.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
```