# Is there any particular font family which can be used for displaying different languages in tcpdf?

Tags: php, tcpdf, font-family

I am trying to generate a pdf file which contains different languages at the same time(like English, French, Chinese, Malay, Thai etc)using PHP and tcpdf. But as I tried, it work for only some languages. Font-family I used is freesans. Can I anybody help me, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

[Noto](https://www.google.com/get/noto/) is a Google free font which is designed for more than 800 languages. Here is a [Guidelines for Using Noto](https://www.google.com/get/noto/help/guidelines/). And here is a [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29896102/how-do-you-add-custom-fonts-in-tcpdf) for how to add custom fonts in tcpdf.

Comment: thanks for the reply and sorry for the delay in my response. Tried the fonts but not able to display malayalam font(notosansmalayalam) correctly some characters are overlapping.

Comment: @Dev sorry I can't read Malayalam, ;-), but could you try to play with the css attribute `letter-spacing`?

Comment: I already tried that option but no luck, now I am trying to do in mpdf instead tcpdf :) anyway thanks @brian17han.